# Can't connect my MySqli to my other classes

Tags: php, mysqli, require

My connection:

```
  <?php
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'audiologiska_kliniken');

    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Ett fel inträffade [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }
```

My class:

```
  <?php
//Display model
require '../include/connect.php';
Class Display
{


    function getData() {
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
        if($result =$db->query= "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = Patient.Patient";`enter code here`
```

The problem: The class doesn't recognize the `$db`. Why is that?

Comment: try adding the global keyword before the $db variable. Not the best way to do it, but this is a scope problem. I suggest to put the connect.php code inside a Class and create a static function for the db connection, or put it in a construct method and extend the Display class with the connect class

Comment: because its out of scope, you could create a connection class and access that, or use it in the constructor

Comment: Why don't you pass as parameter the db object?

Comment: I do now, thank you :) I'm still having trouble connecting. I following the above comment's advice and create a constructor and extend the Display class to it. But I'm not really sure how..

Answer (score 0):

Because you dont pass the variable `$db` to your function, (its not in the function scope)

Change your function to this:

```
function getData($db){
```

and your function call to this:

```
getData($db);
```

that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of scope of variables: you can not see variables from global data inside functions. You can modify your function getData():

```
function getData() {
    global $db;
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    if($result =$db->query= "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = Patient.Patient";`enter code here`
```

But this method isn't "the best". Better way - add connection to your class, i.e.:

```
require '../include/connect.php';
Display::$connection = $db;
Class Display
{
static $connection;
function getData() {
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    if($result =self::$connection->query= "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = Patient.Patient";`enter code here`
```